# Workflow Rule changes in salesforce

Tags: apex, workflow, visualforce-component

I have a Apex class:

```
public class myController {
    public string url{
        get {
            if (this.url == null)
                this.url = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            return this.url; }
        set;
        }

}
```

Visual Force Component:

```
<apex:component controller="myController" access="global">
  <p />
   <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}?isUserEntityOverride=1&amp;noredirect=1</apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```

Visual Force Template in Workflow Rule:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate  recipientType="user"  relatedToType="order">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
   <html>
      <body>
         <center>
            <p>
               <c:URL/> -`/ Here the username will display/`
               <br>
               Click on below link to go to this user setup:
               <c:URL/>/{!$User.Id}"`/ Here the Link will display/`
               </br>
            </p>
         </center>
      </body>
   </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

{!user.name} is not working in the Visual Force Template,so i want to query the current username using the Apex class and then accessed using Visual force Component and   command is used in Visual force template

I Have tried {!$user.username} and {!$user.name} both are not working anyone Guide me for the answer i want the combination of both firstname and Lastname,so i need to query through the apexclass guide me for the answer

**But Now two Requirements   `<c:URL/>` is used to display the link in one Place and   `<c:URL/>`  is used to display the username in another place How? Is it possible in same Component? Please Anyone Guide me for the updated Answer for my Requirement**

Comment: I Have tried {!$user.username} and {!$user.name} both are not working anyone Guide me for the answer i want the combination of both firstname and Lastname

Comment: If we querying through apex class means if we want we can query phone also,My thought  is possible ah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the username, FirstName and LastName, using the below format

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Label.URL}/{! $User.Id}" >{!$Label.URL}/{! $User.FirstName}{! $User.LastName}</apex:outputLink>
```

So, your URL will still redirect the end-users to the correct uri, while for display it would have **LastName** and **FirstName**.

Your output should look something like the one below, in which you see that the link label is `domain/username` while the link address is still valid as it is `domain/userid`.

[image]

Define two properties in your controller, namely, usrName and usrPhone.

```
Public String usrName {get;set;} 
Public String usrPhone {get;set;}

user usr = [select name,phone from user where id =:userinfo.getuserid() LIMIT 1];

usrName = usr.Name;
usrPhone = usr.Phone;
```

In your VF component

```
<apex:component controller="myController" access="global"> 
  <p /> 
  <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}?isUserEntityOverride=1&amp;noredirect=1</apex:outputLink> <br />

  <apex:outputLabel value="{!usrName}" id="someId" />
  <apex:outputLabel value="{!usrPhone}" id="someId2" />

</apex:component>
```